# Google Query Language - searching entire table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I3N5DtdXGWFootaOCQM201K_ao2ZPWSWyw9_l7QcwQg/) that contains many many columns of data.  I'm retrieving that data using a query.

If I say

```
query.setQuery("select A where D contains 'Ambassador'");
```

as expected, I get just the first column where fourth column contains the data I'm searching for.

However, if I say

```
query.setQuery("select A where * contains 'Ambassador'");
```

I get an error,

> Error in query: INVALID_QUERY Invalid query: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered
>   " "*" "* "" at line 1, column 16.

How can I search across the entire Database for the text I'm seeking?  Is the only way to say "where B contains ... or C contains ..."?

(Yes, I know that spreadsheet is not well-optimized at the moment.  I intend to fix that once I get this search thing sorted out.)

Comment: Have you ever tried  using textfinder?

Comment: `Is the only way to say "where B contains ... or C contains ..."?` I believe so.

Answer (score 0):

**Using TextFinder to Find Ambassador**

These are all of the locations that contain 'Ambassador' in your spreadsheet using [textfinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#createTextFinder(String)).  The search was very fast.

```
Sheet: Crew_Traits Cell: D1 Row: 1 Col: 4 Value: Ambassador
Sheet: Crew_Traits Cell: D13 Row: 13 Col: 4 Value: Ambassador
Sheet: Crew_Traits Cell: A30 Row: 30 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Fox
Sheet: Crew_Traits Cell: A31 Row: 31 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador K'Ehleyr
Sheet: Crew_Traits Cell: D31 Row: 31 Col: 4 Value: Ambassador
Sheet: Crew_Traits Cell: A32 Row: 32 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Neelix
Sheet: Crew_Traits Cell: D32 Row: 32 Col: 4 Value: Ambassador
Sheet: Crew_Traits Cell: A33 Row: 33 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Sarek
Sheet: Crew_Traits Cell: A34 Row: 34 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Shras
Sheet: Crew_Traits Cell: D34 Row: 34 Col: 4 Value: Ambassador
Sheet: Crew_Traits Cell: A35 Row: 35 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Soval
Sheet: Crew_Traits Cell: A36 Row: 36 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Spock
Sheet: Crew_Traits Cell: A37 Row: 37 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Troi
Sheet: 1* Cell: A31 Row: 31 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Fox
Sheet: 1* Cell: A32 Row: 32 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador K'Ehleyr
Sheet: 1* Cell: A33 Row: 33 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Neelix
Sheet: 1* Cell: A34 Row: 34 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Sarek
Sheet: 1* Cell: A35 Row: 35 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Shras
Sheet: 1* Cell: A36 Row: 36 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Soval
Sheet: 1* Cell: A37 Row: 37 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Spock
Sheet: 1* Cell: A38 Row: 38 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Troi
Sheet: 2* Cell: A31 Row: 31 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Fox
Sheet: 2* Cell: A32 Row: 32 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador K'Ehleyr
Sheet: 2* Cell: A33 Row: 33 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Neelix
Sheet: 2* Cell: A34 Row: 34 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Sarek
Sheet: 2* Cell: A35 Row: 35 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Shras
Sheet: 2* Cell: A36 Row: 36 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Soval
Sheet: 2* Cell: A37 Row: 37 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Spock
Sheet: 2* Cell: A38 Row: 38 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Troi
Sheet: 3* Cell: A30 Row: 30 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Fox
Sheet: 3* Cell: A31 Row: 31 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador K'Ehleyr
Sheet: 3* Cell: A32 Row: 32 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Neelix
Sheet: 3* Cell: A33 Row: 33 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Sarek
Sheet: 3* Cell: A34 Row: 34 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Shras
Sheet: 3* Cell: A35 Row: 35 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Soval
Sheet: 3* Cell: A36 Row: 36 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Spock
Sheet: 3* Cell: A37 Row: 37 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Troi
Sheet: 4* Cell: A29 Row: 29 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador K'Ehleyr
Sheet: 4* Cell: A30 Row: 30 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Sarek
Sheet: 4* Cell: A31 Row: 31 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Shras
Sheet: 4* Cell: A32 Row: 32 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Soval
Sheet: 4* Cell: A33 Row: 33 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Spock
Sheet: 4* Cell: A34 Row: 34 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Troi
Sheet: 5* Cell: A19 Row: 19 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Soval
Sheet: 5* Cell: A20 Row: 20 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Troi
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: A31 Row: 31 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Fox
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: B31 Row: 31 Col: 2 Value: /wiki/Ambassador_Fox
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: A32 Row: 32 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador K'Ehleyr
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: B32 Row: 32 Col: 2 Value: /wiki/Ambassador_K%27Ehleyr
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: A33 Row: 33 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Neelix
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: B33 Row: 33 Col: 2 Value: /wiki/Ambassador_Neelix
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: A34 Row: 34 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Sarek
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: B34 Row: 34 Col: 2 Value: /wiki/Ambassador_Sarek
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: A35 Row: 35 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Shras
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: B35 Row: 35 Col: 2 Value: /wiki/Ambassador_Shras
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: A36 Row: 36 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Soval
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: B36 Row: 36 Col: 2 Value: /wiki/Ambassador_Soval
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: A37 Row: 37 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Spock
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: B37 Row: 37 Col: 2 Value: /wiki/Ambassador_Spock
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: A38 Row: 38 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Troi
Sheet: Crew_URLs Cell: B38 Row: 38 Col: 2 Value: /wiki/Ambassador_Troi
Sheet: Crew_Basics Cell: A31 Row: 31 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Fox
Sheet: Crew_Basics Cell: A32 Row: 32 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador K'Ehleyr
Sheet: Crew_Basics Cell: A33 Row: 33 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Neelix
Sheet: Crew_Basics Cell: A34 Row: 34 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Sarek
Sheet: Crew_Basics Cell: A35 Row: 35 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Shras
Sheet: Crew_Basics Cell: A36 Row: 36 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Soval
Sheet: Crew_Basics Cell: A37 Row: 37 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Spock
Sheet: Crew_Basics Cell: A38 Row: 38 Col: 1 Value: Ambassador Troi
```

This is the code:
sObj.ssid is the id of your spreadsheet
sObj.pattern is a reqular expression patter in this case it was 'Ambassador' without the quotes.

```
function regexSearch(sObj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(sObj.ssid);
  var tf=ss.createTextFinder(sObj.pattern).useRegularExpression(true);
  var all=tf.findAll();
  var matches='';
  for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++) {
    matches+=Utilities.formatString('Sheet: %s Cell: %s Row: %s Col: %s Value: %s\n',all[i].getSheet().getName(),all[i].getA1Notation(),all[i].getRow(),all[i].getColumn(),all[i].getValue());
  }
  if(matches) {
    sObj.matches=matches;
  }else{
    sObj.message(Utilities.formatString('No Matches found for %s',sObj.pattern));
  }
  return sObj;
}
```

With a couple of little tweaks to the above code we get these results:

```
Sheet: Crew_Traits Row: 13 Col: 4 Value: Ambassador columnA Value: Admiral Picard
Sheet: Crew_Traits Row: 31 Col: 4 Value: Ambassador columnA Value: Ambassador K'Ehleyr
Sheet: Crew_Traits Row: 32 Col: 4 Value: Ambassador columnA Value: Ambassador Neelix
Sheet: Crew_Traits Row: 34 Col: 4 Value: Ambassador columnA Value: Ambassador Shras
```

and now this is the code:

```
function regexSearch() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1I3N5DtdXGWFootaOCQM201K_ao2ZPWSWyw9_l7QcwQg');
  var tf=ss.createTextFinder('Ambassador').useRegularExpression(true);
  var all=tf.findAll();
  var matches='';
  for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++) {
    if(all[i].getColumn()==4) {
      var aValue=all[i].getSheet().getRange(all[i].getRow(),1).getValue();
      matches+=Utilities.formatString('Sheet: %s Row: %s Col: %s Value: %s columnA Value: %s\n',all[i].getSheet().getName(),all[i].getRow(),all[i].getColumn(),all[i].getValue(),aValue);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(matches);
  return matches;  
}
```